# TypeScript generic type and default function application

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have the following TS code:

```
export interface Id<T> {
  (arg: T): T;
}

export function IdFunc<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

I want to use the Id and IdFunc like so to provide a default implementation of `transformer`.

```
interface Options {
  transformer: Id<number>;
}

const defaultOptions : Options = {
  transformer: IdFunc<number>
               ^^^ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Id<number>'
}
```

But I get an error when doing this, is there a way to accomplish using function name + type for the default option without doing something like this:

```
const myIdentity: Id<number> = IdFunc;

const defaultOptions : Options = {
  transformer: myIdentity
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBMAeAFQD44BvAKDjgApMoBzALjlIEoPSBuGgF8aNUJFhx0AVyTYYCCEgKEAYjOxlyTVrx6dqdOFGAwpUJcxYDhNZKgw48AeTDzFAZwP0YUTEnfo0AC2aBxExEhSQQBGaOTWItge8EEAnkTAKAgwqWEkkTFxcAC8ymqyAjRJ-vCEwFhSADYwLm7+cBytCu2ltN6+-oFQIVB55RoFsVDkQiI0APQAVAvzBHCEigDk8ADufvAwEOtHMAAWCO5sVclwaRlZOXkRUVOUpUTjldXutfWYTS1XN1PJ0gR4Sl44D4-AFgqFbuk6g9UrNFvM5jQgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function IdFunc` is a function which takes an argument of type `T` and returns a value of the same type `T`.  It is a generic function, so it can be called with any value.

The interface `Id<T>` defines a function which is not generic.  The interface itself is generic, but `Id<number>` defines a non-generic function that looks like `(arg: number) => number`.

It is perfectly fine to create your `Options` by including the generic `IdFunc` as your `transformer`.  When called with a `number` it will return a `number`, so it is assignable to `Id<number>`

```
const defaultOptions : Options = {
  transformer: IdFunc,
}
```

You cannot use `IdFunc<number>` as a value because the generic is set when the function is called.  It's not something that you can set beforehand (at least with this current signature).  You will get an error "`number` only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzYem)